# pass array of objects using $http angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

this is what i tried,

```
var items = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:5}];   
$http.put("/url",{data:items}).then(function(response){
     .... 
    ....    
  });
```

What i am getting in server is

```
params: { invtransactionserviceData: [ [Object] ] } }
```

where this goes wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Use angular.toJson() because the serialization of that data is not automatic.

Answer (score 1):

You Must be use JSON.stringify Method. because Object not send to server so convert to string then send to server

`var items = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:5}];

$http.put("/url",{data:JSON.stringify(items)}).then(function(response){
     .... 
    ....

  });`

Answer (score 0):

Use $.param() to serialize your data before passing it

```
$http.put("/url",{data:$.param(items)}).then(function(response){
 .... 
....    
});
```